# Terraform expression to skip a resource based on key = false in tfvars map, using for_each

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

```
resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "script" {
  for_each = {
    for k, v in var.vm_map : k => v
    if v["startup_script"] != "false" || startup_script doesnt exist
  }
  ...
}
```

```
vm_map = {
    fileserver = {
      name            = "qlikviewserver"
      machine_type    = "n1-standard-8"
      zone            = "europe-west1-b"
      ip              = "11.111.111.11"
      os              = "windows"
      service         = "qlikview"
      boot_disk_image = "windows-2016-base-latest"
      boot_disk_size  = "120"
      boot_disk_type  = "pd-ssd"
      policy          = "daily"
      enable_display  = true
      startup_script  = false
    }
  }
```

Please can someone help with the "startup_script doesnt exist" pseudocode.
I want the script to deploy the google_storage_bucket_object if startup_script = true or startup_script is missing completely.  I want terraform to skip this resource if startup_script = false.

It needs to be a for_each because I'm importing resources dependent on this existing code.  Why someone decided to create them manually in GCP, bypassing terraform, I will never know.  I asked, they didn't reply.

ChatGPT suggested:

```
for_each = {
  for k, v in var.vm_map : k => v
  if !contains(keys(v), "startup_script") || v["startup_script"] != "false"
}
```

Error: Invalid index

if !contains(keys(v), "startup_script") || v["startup_script"] != "false"

The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.

Then tried:

```
for_each = {
  for k, v in var.vm_map : 
  v["startup_script"] != "false" || !can(v["startup_script"]) ? k => v : null
}
```

Error: Missing false expression in conditional
│
│   on google_compute_instance.tf line 50, in resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "script":
│   50: v["startup_script"] != "false" || !can(v["startup_script"]) ? k => v : null
│
│ The conditional operator (...?...:...) requires a false expression, delimited by a colon.
╵

╷
│ Error: Invalid 'for' expression
│
│   on google_compute_instance.tf line 50, in resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "script":
│   48:   for_each = {
│   49:     for k, v in var.vm_map :
│   50: v["startup_script"] != "false" || !can(v["startup_script"]) ? k => v : null
│
│ Extra characters after the end of the 'for' expression.

Answer (score 0):

What about (referring to https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/howto-filter-element-of-map/4434/2)?

```
resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "script" {
  for_each = {
    for k, v in var.vm_map : k => v
    if v.startup_script == true
  }
  
  ...
 }
```

Comment: I think the issue here is that there can be cases where the `startup_script` key does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Terraform logic operators do not short-circuit ([docs](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/operators#logical-operators)), thus each branch is evaluated, and if either produces an error, then Terraform errors.

The solution to your problem may be using `try`:

```
for_each = {
  for k, v in var.vm_map : k => v if try(v.["startup_script"], false) == true
}
```

Using `try`, if the left expression errors (e.g. when the `startup_script` key is missing), then the right one is evaluated, thus falling back on `false` in this case.

Comment: Modified your script, the below works:

`for_each = {
    for k, v in var.vm_map : k => v if try(v["startup_script"], "true") == "true"
  }`

So if in the vm_map startup_script = true, then the expression evaluates true==true as true.  
If startup_script doesn't exist, then it defaults to true, thus true==true and the expression returns true.
If startup_script = false, then the false == true, which is evaluated as false.

Comment: Now just have to test it, add a fileserver2 = {...} to the vm_map and see if different permutations work. eg. for fileserver2 startup_script = true and for fileserver startup_script = false.

Comment: Oh so you have a map of maps, I tried with a map of objects and it worked. I edit the answer to adjust it.

Comment: tested 

vm_map = {
    fileserver = {...}
    fileserver2 = {...}
}

with various combinations of startup_script = false, startup_script = true, no startup_script it all worked with the code I posted above.

Many thanks Lorenzo Felletti, I wouldn't have gotten there without your tip.

Comment: Also for some reason terraform didn't like the "true" without the double quotes.  ie. for_each = { for k, v in var.vm_map : k => v if try(v["startup_script"], true) == true } doesn't work!  But it works with the quotes.

Comment: @Wysong what version of terraform are you on? And also, are you sure vm_map is the same you shared in the question (regarding types)? Finally, what is the new error you are getting?

Comment: It all works now, thanks Lorenzo!

Comment: I am using Terraform v0.12.31 and the vm_map has this in the variables.tf 

variable "vm_map" {
  default = {}
}

Exactly what I posted above in the 2nd code block from the top in the .tfvars file.

Comment: oh ok, so you're on a pretty old version of Terraform, this may explain the differences to make the code work (I was testing with v1.5.7).

Comment: Terraform v0.12 is _incredibly_ obsolete and so you should plan to upgrade as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing complicated expressions to deal with various different ways a caller could specify a value, you could define the type of this input variable so that the objects will always have all of the expected attributes:

```
variable "vm_map" {
  type = map(
    object({
      name            = string
      machine_type    = string
      zone            = string
      ip              = string
      os              = string
      service         = string
      boot_disk_image = string
      boot_disk_size  = number
      boot_disk_type  = string
      policy          = string
      enable_display  = bool
      startup_script  = optional(bool, false)
    })
  )
}
```

With a declaration like the above, Terraform will ensure that `var.vm_map` is always of the specified type. In particular, the `optional` modified on `startup_script` means that if the caller omits that argument then Terraform will automatically set it to `false`.

You can then write your `for_each` expression like this:

```
resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "script" {
  for_each = {
    for k, v in var.vm_map : k => v
    if v.startup_script
  }

  # ...
}
```

`v.startup_script` can only possibly be `true` or `false` when the input variable's type is properly declared, so there's no need to add any extra complexity to this expression to handle other types.